# Back button in canon

Tags: canon, back-button-autofocus

I recently changed my camera to the back button focus instead of the half shutter settings. But now that I focus pressing the back button to focus and then shoot with the shutter I was wondering if I should leave on the auto focus mode on? ... that option is located in the menu. Should i just leave it off or on? does it make any difference? Im using a canon t5i rebel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you turn AF off pressing the back button set to initiate AF will not do anything. To focus your lens you would need to turn the focus ring on the lens. But as far as I am aware, all Canon EOS cameras use the AF/M switch on the lens, not a menu option in the camera, to turn AF off or on. The options in the menu are for selecting which AF mode you wish to use and whether the back button is used to initiate AF or used to stop AF (if it is initiated by a half press of the shutter) or used for Auto Exposure Lock.

To put it another way: using back button focus is still using autofocus. You're just separating your instruction to the camera on when to autofocus from your instruction to the camera on when to meter and when to take a picture.

Comment: this is the correct answer. Source have a t4i that is basically the same as the t5i.